# CSRF Validation failed

Tags: 7, services

I have created an angular application with headless Drupal. I am using Drupal Services module for web services call from my angular application.

My angular app contains login mechanism which is done using services call. So on login, session id, session name and token are saved and after for each request like GET, POST, PUT, I am using those stored values to authenticate the user at Drupal to do the backend logic.

This session storage is suggested at Drupal service module documentation.

So what happening to me is, on my POST and PUT call, Service module can't able to identify the user and returns "CSRF validation Failed".

On debugging the service module, in this function "_services_sessions_authenticate_call" they are allowing only certain http methods like GET, HEAD, OPTIONS. Hence my POST and PUT call is not allowed and returned as "CSRF Failed".

After modifying the code by allowing POST and PUT in that function, everything works great.

I think modifying the stable module code is not a suggested one. Am I doing anything wrong in request handling or can anyone suggest a standard way to handle authentication?

Comment: Check once the input you are sending.

Comment: You shouldn't disable that check, it's for security. Just make sure you're sending the token you get back from the token endpoint in the `HTTP_X_CSRF_TOKEN` header from JS

Comment: @Clive okay. I will do that.  is my user authentication handling was correct in my angular app? (like storing session id and session name, and using them with token for each request)

Comment: A CSRF token is separate from your session tokens, and it needs to be generated for each POST/PUT by making a GET request to `/services/session/token'`.

Comment: Services co-maintainer here... the header name is `X-CSRF-Token` and POST/PUT will work just fine, provided your web host allows those http methods.

Comment: Actually I can't able to use Cookie header in angular http call. So as a workaround, in Drupal hook unit I am adding cookie with session name. I think this issue is related to that I used this link for workaroundhttps://www.drupal.org/node/1133084  check #5

Comment: @mradcliffe /services/session/token using this generated token will allow to do POST or PUT request, but in backend current user is identified as anonymous. I mean global $user returns uid as 0

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein can you please advice something for this questions "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/234257/30410"?